# Unable to run Profile management Tool for Websphere 7.0 from within RAD 7.5

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, rad

I am using Rational Application Developer version 7.5.4 on 64-bit Windows OS (i5). I would like to create custom profiles for development. We hav been using RAD 7.5.4 on Windows XP before. On Windows 7 (64 bit) machines the  "**Run Profile Management Tool**" button is **disabled**.Any help on how to get the PMT to run on 64 bit machine is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it is too late but you need to do right-click and select "Run as Administrator". You have to do it even if you are already logged in as Administrator.

Answer (score 2):

After a two day struggle I have hit a solution to get the PMT to run on Windows 7 (64 bit). Download the [manageProfilesInteractive](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21442487) batch file and run to create and manage profile.

Answer (score 0):

Try running RAD as Administrator.

Comment: In fact, when you do not run as administrator, it's the Delete button below that is disabled and profiles are marked as read-only. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that since you're on 64-bit platform, WebSphere AS (that RAD comes with) is also 64-bit, and no PMT is available. That's why I think the Run PMT button is disabled.

Quoting [Creating application server profiles](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/tpro_instancessaappserv.html):

> Supported configurations: You cannot use the Profile Management Tool
>   to create profiles for WebSphere Application Server installations on
>   64-bit architectures except on the Linux for zSeries platform.
>   However, you can use the Profile Management Tool on other 64–bit
>   architectures if you use a WebSphere Application Server 32–bit
>   installation.

I can't find a relevant information from [Rational Application Developer's Information Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp).

Comment: your answer should go as a comment. It doesn't provide any directions on how to get the PMT to run. May be an alternative should be good.

Comment: There's no PMT on 64-bit platforms and that's a short answer. You should revert to using manageprofiles or the batch file you mentioned below as an alternative yet not distributed with the server binaries.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I installed the Liberty servers on a new installation of RAD 9.1 and apparently they do not come with the "manageprofiles.sh" which disables the Run Profile Management button. To fix this, I installed the non-Liberty servers and then I was able to use the profile management tool.